# send selected columnsof gridview to an excel file

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I have tried code for saving entire gridview data to an excel file and it is working fine but now i want to save only particular columns of gridview to an excel file.I have used mysql database and asp.net with C#.Please  anyone help me with this.

```
**default.aspx**
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save to Excel" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

**default.cs**
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportGridToExcel(GridView1, "StudentMarks.xls");
    }

    public void ExportGridToExcel(GridView grdGridView, string fileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        grdGridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        return;
    }
```

[image: this is my gridview]

[image: this is the excel file which is generated]

Comment: Show your code and tell people what have you tried so far..

Comment: may this link solution solve your issue-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940895/export-datagridview-with-padding-to-excel/15941307#15941307

Comment: You can use a method to generate excel which is mention in above comment link.

Comment: but in this link there is no way to select particular columns of gridview and then save only those columns to an excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp:boundfield to select the columns which you want to display in the gridview. Then export that gridview to excel.

Ok.In your case you can bind a new gridview with same data but without Edit/Delete column.  You can set the visibility of this new gridview to false.

Comment: can you please give me the complete code for how to save only selected columns to an excel file

Comment: actually i am having a gridview in which i have the first column in which i have used two images one is for edit and one is for delete operation.So now when i apply the above code i am getting that column of edit/delete also.But i only want to save data in excel file not that column.So please tell how to achieve this

Comment: ya i know this is the solution or we can use dataset object also rather than gridview but what if i want to save only particular columns of gridview to an excel file...check this link http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net-GridView-Export-only-selected-columns-to-Excel-Sheet.aspx

Comment: i have tried this but not working fine for me...if you can then please take help from this but give me this code for mysql

Comment: Can you check the link you posted. Unable to open it.

Comment: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net-GridView-Export-only-selected-columns-to-Excel-Sheet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To generate excel use this method ..

```
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView.AllowPaging = false;

            // Re-Bind data to GridView 

            using (MSEntities1 CompObj = new MSEntities1())
            {
               // code for bind grid view 
                GridView.DataBind();
            }

            // Change the Header Row back to white color

            GridViewC.Style.Add(" font-size", "10px");

            GridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");


            //Apply style to Individual Cells

            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Style.Add("background-color", "green");


            int k = GridView.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i < GridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                GridViewRow row = GridView.Rows[i];


                //Change Color back to white

                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;


                //Apply text style to each Row

                row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");


                //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row

                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                    row.Cells[7].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                }
            }
            GridView.RenderControl(hw);

            // style to format numbers to string.

            string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";

            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: but in this method where we are checking which columns of gridview we want to save to an excel file?

Comment: which column you want to store in excel ,according to which criteria

Comment: see above in my gridview i have first column for edit/delete,now i dont want to save this column in my excel file

Comment: ok then  you can re-bind the data in function acording to row id and then generate excel like i have re-bind all data here you can put query and get those column which you want in excel     --   // Re-Bind data to GridView 

            using (MSEntities1 CompObj = new MSEntities1())
            {
               // code for bind grid view 
                GridView.DataBind();
            }

Comment: can you please explain in detail and give the sample code for the same

Comment: means you can get the data which you want to show inexcel in any data table at btnExportExcel_Click function and then bind the data table to grid view and then create execl , so the new data according to your query(which you get in data table)show in excel